# Prepare audit events based on domain models

Tags: spring-boot, audit, hexagonal-architecture

I have application which acts as a proxy between different systems without own database. There are few possible use cases which are covered by the application:

1. Display data from specific system or systems
2. Store data to specific system or systems

Actually this application has their own front-end and back-end (with sping boot and angular stack). And back-end is responsible to get/put data from/to external systems and front-end communicates with the back-end and it does not know anything about external systems. Also, the back-end follows hexagonal architecture and has their own defined domain models.

Currently there are requirements to cover auditing for business use cases related to the application. For instance, if user goes to some feature related to the application and make some changes there, it should be audited.

I've googled this topic on the internet but I only found entity based auditing like this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html. For my case I would need something similar but based on domain models rather then on entities.

Could you please recommend some direction to cover this? Actually which library or so can be used for such use case to use state of domain model to prepare audit events. I've found something like this https://logging.apache.org/log4j-audit/latest/gettingStarted.html, but I am really not sure if it is rigth way to go

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can build your own auditing strategy based on events.
Let us take the example you gave: "if user goes to some feature related to the application and make some changes there, it should be audited.".

I assume you have a service that handles these requests from a REST API or something similar. That same service would not only communicate with the external systems but would also publish an event with let's say the information about the user and the performed changes or updated (here you can rely on Redis for example, but there are other options like RabbitMQ or even Kafka, depending on how reliable you want your auditing feature to be).

Then you would have another component of your app listening for these events so that you can store them in a Database (I guess that is the purpose). Or you can even have a separated micro-service only for this purpose, depending on how complex this auditing system is meant to be.

If you want something more "magical" and automated you can try to take a look at Spring Boot Data Audit code to see how it is implemented, but you might end up building an overengineered solution.